# python slightly modified Collatz Conjecture program

Tags: python, collatz

I was given an assignment writing a Collatz Conjecture program, modified like so:

> 1. We know the program ALWAYS divides by 4 on even numbers, even ones not divisible by 4, so the next step after 6 would be 6/4 == 1.
> 2. We know the program always reached a stop condition even with the alternative behavior, not sure if there was another change in the code...

and it need to

> 1. count the number of steps from n until we reach a stop condition
> 2. return the sum of all the steps in Shortz(n) including n itself

as a final answer, I need to return (the sum of all steps of 737458374680773)*(the number of steps of 98325112)

The problem is when I calculate this one: 737458374680773 it goes into infinite loop.

As for this hint:

> not sure if there was another change in the code...

I don't think I need to change anything with the odd numbers formula because it would be too far fetched in my opinion (but hey I don't know much, enlighten me :) ).

Any ideas as to what's the problem with my code or what I didn't get regarding the assignment?

This is my code:

```
import math
def shortz(num):
    iterations = 0
    stepsSum = 0
    while( math.isnan(num) or num<0):
        num = int(input("Please supply a non-negative number ==>  "))
        print("")
    while(num !=1):
         if (num%2==0):
             num /= 4 
             stepsSum += num       
             print (str(iterations+1) + ") " + str(num))
         else:
             num = (num*3) -1
             print (str(iterations+1) + ") "+ str(num))
         iterations += 1 
         stepsSum += num
    print ("the number of iterations is " + str(iterations))
    print ("the sum of all steps is " + str(stepsSum))

q=0
while (q<1):
    x = int(input("Input positive number: "))
    shortz(x)
    z = str(input("Again?")).lower()
    if z[0]=='n':
        q=2
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic mishandles '2' and goes into an infinite loop:

2/4 is 0.5 -> (0.5 * 3) - 1 -> 0.5 -> (0.5 * 3) - 1 -> 0.5, etc.

```
Input positive number: 2
1) 0.5
2) 0.5
3) 0.5
4) 0.5
5) 0.5
6) 0.5
7) 0.5
...
```

You may need to use `num //= 4` instead of `num /= 4` to get rid of the fractional part.  But that doesn't fix this glitch, just changes the repeating result from 0.5 to 0.

> not sure if there was another change in the code...

Likely refers to how to handle zero.  It's not a positive integer, so not a valid input to `shortz()` but it still comes up as an internal result (if you use `//`) and so has to be dealt with specially. (Ditto for 0.5 if you continue to use `/`)

Perhaps something as simple as changing:

```
while(num !=1):
```

to instead be:

```
while num > 1:
```

This (along with using `//`) allows both your example numbers to resolve.

Comment: Great analysis! (in my eyes :) )
I think it might be it but will know only next week. thanks a lot.